# How do you paste multiple tabbed lines into Vi?

Tags: vim, vi

I want to paste something I have cut from my desktop into a file open in Vi.

But if I paste the tabs embed on top of each other across the page.

I think it is some sort of visual mode change but can't find the command.

Comment: This isn't off topic, people still program in vi and vim

Comment: This question is not off topic.  I just came here because I was trying to copy paste into vi while programming and had trouble with auto indent.

Comment: On Unix you can use  :r!cat<ENTER> , then paste, then type <CTRL-D>  when it's done.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### If you're using plain vi:

You probably have `autoindent` on. To turn it off while pasting:

```
<Esc> :set noai

<paste all you want>

<Esc> :set ai
```

I have in my `.exrc` the following shortcuts:

```
map ^P :set noai^M
map ^N :set ai^M
```

Note that these have to be the actual control characters - insert them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and so on.

### If you're using vim:

Use the [`paste`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/options.html#%27paste%27) option. In addition to disabling `autoindent` it will also set other options such as `textwidth` and `wrapmargin` to paste-friendly defaults:

```
<Esc> :set paste

<paste all you want>

<Esc> :set nopaste
```

You can also set a key to toggle the paste mode. My `.vimrc` has the following line:

```
set pastetoggle=<C-P> " Ctrl-P toggles paste mode
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VIM, you can use "*p (i.e. double quotes, asterisk, letter p).

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I copy tabbed lines first into a text editor and then recopy them from there to vim, then the tabs are correct.